# Passbook passes

Tags: ios

We all had a chance to view Passbook passes in iOS. Some passes display consumer name attached to it and some don't. 
  We see value in displaying names for airline passes which would help us to identify the passenger, but unable to understand on rewards cards like Starbucks and AMC. All they are going to do is scan and the POS is going to display the name. 
 Can anyone help me understand what is the intent behind displaying consumer names in passes that act as rewards cards.

Answer (score 1):

Names on the cards/passes give customers sense of recognition and personalization.

- **Recognition:** addressing a customer by his/her name is a very meaningful and treasured detail that adds greatly to the way they experience doing business with you. People feel they are valued and remembered by the business.
- **Personalization:** names on cards give customers a sense of personalization and sense of closeness with the organization.
- **Brand Alignment:** by putting the name on the card, you are putting the brand and person on the "same team".

Comment: Good answer, Salman. I added a note about brand alignment that I thought was relevant.

Comment: Thanks Salman and designerguy. Just curious if it is direct meet and greet all this would have impact, but in a card do you still feel this would create a sense of closeness.